# Java Arrays 2 x 2 and how they work

Tags: java

http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm

I was taking a look at that link above under the "Array of Objects" section.

This code is given from the above link

```
for (int i=0; i < board.length ; i++)

   for (int j=0; j < board[i].length ; j++)

      board[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
```

Can someone explain to me in detail for newbies that snippet of code and how it works to fill in the grid with random integers especially the part with

```
  board.length
```

and

```
  board[i].length
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a tutorial site.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.  You can find _many_ explanations online if you search for "Java 2d array", most with pictures. Before posting here in future please be sure you have exhausted basic web searches.

Comment: Alright sorry Ill just delete my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`board` is a 2D-array, in other words, it's **an array of arrays**. Let's say it's:

```
int board[][] = new int[3][2]; // 3 rows, 2 columns
```

The expression `board.length` is accessing to the public attribute `length` from the `board` array, you should consider here that `board` is an array, but its elements are also arrays.

```
board.length // 3 elements (3 rows)
```

Then, you are iterating through indexes `for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)`. `i` will take values from `0` to `board.length-1` (because of `<`)

So, on each iteration you are accessing to the length of the current element:

```
board[i] // element (an array, because `board` is an array of arrays)
board[i].length // access to the length of that array, which will be 2
```

Finally, when you access to `board[i][j]`, you are accessing to an element of an element of `board`. In other words, you are accessing to an element of an array, and this array is an element of the 2D-array `board`.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure that you are referring to is an array containing **references**. In the diagram below, `b[0]`, `b[1]` and `b[2]` are references towards the arrays [A,B,C], [D], and [E,F] respectively. Therefore, `b.length = 3`, as it contains three references.

```
+------+      +---+---+---+
|      | ---> | A | B | C | => b[0].length=3 (its elements are b[0][0]=A, b[0][1]=B, b[0][2]=C)
| b[0] |      +---+---+---+
|      |     
+------+      +---+
|      | ---> | D | => b[1].length=1 (its only element is b[1][0]=D)
| b[1] |      +---+
|      |
+------+      +---+---+
|      | ---> | E | F | => b[2].length=2 (its elements are b[2][0]=E, b[2][1]=F)
| b[2] |      +---+---+
|      |
+------+
   => b.length = 3 (its elements are b[0]=[A,B,C], b[1]=[D,E], b[2]=[F])
```

The nested for loops in your code will visit each cell in the diagram, from left to right, top to bottom. The purpose of `i` is to iterate over the rows, that is, to indicate that one must visit `b[0]`, then `b[1]`, then `b[2]`. The purpose of `j` is to iterate over the cells in one row, that is, to indicate that when `i=0` we must visit columns 0, 1, and 2 to find A, B, and c. When `i=1`, `j` visits column 0 and finds D. Finally, when `i=2`, `j` visits columns 0 and 1 to find E and F.